# Should I use asyncio or thread pool for gain performance in api requests?

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, request, python-asyncio

I want to make a real time face recognizer with azure cognitive service's face api. But the api calls takes so much time. What concept should I use in that situation?

I wrote my code in the simple while loop. Grap a frame and detect faces in that frame. But the request part for detection faces is takes ~2.5 seconds. So, it's soooo far from real time detection :) I found a c# example at their website but i couldn't handle. The link is : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/face-api-how-to-topics/howtoanalyzevideo_face

```
while True:
    image = getCapture()
    cv2.imshow('image', image)
    image = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)[1].tostring()
    response = requests.post(vision_analyze_url,
                             params=params,
                             headers=headers,
                             data=image)
    print(response.json())
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
```

I want to make this real time but I think it's impossible :/ So I can save video and make requests with batches of this images, or I can make this two jobs simultaneously. What can I do? I have to do that in 2 days :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But the request part for detection faces is takes ~2.5 seconds. [...] I want to make this real time

You could submit requests in parallel to increase processing throughput. To upgrade from the current 0.4 fps to 25 fps (real-time), you would have to submit ~625 requests in parallel. You'd still have a latency of 2.5s, but the delay would be constant. Unless your backend has 600+ cores, or it's running on a cluster, this is unlikely to work. But if you want to try, the code that runs requests in parallel could look like this:

```
import concurrent.futures, itertools, functools

pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1000)

def on_complete(frameno, future):
    response = future.result()
    print(frameno, response.json())

for frameno in itertools.count(start=1):
    image = getCapture()
    cv2.imshow('image', image)
    image = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)[1].tostring()
    future = pool.submit(lambda: requests.post(vision_analyze_url,
        params=params, headers=headers, data=image))
    future.add_done_callback(functools.partial(on_complete, frameno))
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
```

This uses threads; asyncio is not a good fit for this problem because you are using the non-async `cv2` library which would block the event loop.

Comment: I decided to save an input video and than make parallel requests with it. This is my code, I would really appreciate it, if you could review it. :)
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bcPT3Jp6th/

Comment: @CanSözbir That looks like the same general approach as in my answer, except you first collect the pictures and then send them for processing, whereas my answer attempted to do it in real time.